# Stored procedure for PostgreSQL on Liquibase Community

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I read on Wikipedia that you need the Commercial version of Liquibase to deal with stored procedures. Can anybody please comment on this?

Thanks

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't.

I typically put the code to create the function and procedure into a SQL script and then use  to run it. The changeSet itself is defined as `runOnChange=true` so I only need to edit the file to make Liquibase apply the changeset

```xml
<changeSet id="1" author="foo" runOnChange="true">
   <sqlFile path="procs/create_function.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

I do the same with views and materialized views.

Comment: can you give syntax for adding stored postgres procedures using liquidbase , i am unable to figure it out , it will be extremely helpful .

Comment: @shadow0wolf: as I wrote in the answer: put the appropriate `create procedure` statement in a SQL file, then include it as shown above. The necessary SQL syntax is documented in the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)

Answer (score 2):

Liquibase community manager here.

As described in the answer by @a_horse_with_no_name, it is entirely possible to write a Liquibase changelog that creates stored procedures that will work just fine in the free version.

To do that you can use the XML changelog syntax with a `<sql>` or `<sqlFile>` tag, or you could use a formatted sql changelog.

The thing that the Pro version of Liquibase introduces is the ability to use the `generateChangeLog` and `diffChangeLog` commands to "reverse-engineer" stored logic (including stored procedures) from an existing database, generating XML changelogs that use the `<createProcedure>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. There are two options that are available for stored procedures/stored logic: Liquibase Pro or Datical. You can get a free trial for Liquibase Pro to try them out to make sure they work for you at www.liquibase.org.